# Alipay Payment GateWay not getting response in notify URL

Tags: alipay

I am integrating Alipay payment gateway in my website, I have download SDK from Alipay website and using their sample code. My payment is being made successfully but I am not getting response in notify url. I want to update my DB in notify URL. Any body can help me ? How i can get response in notify URL.

Thanks,

Comment: Please, provide more details about url you are using as `notify_url`. It should be public, without authentication system or redirects. Specify protocol explicitly, e.g. `https://my.url`